# Executing Javascript within a div in Django

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, image-uploading

I am trying to configure a modified version of Biostars on a Django server for a university project to help engineering students communicate between different years, (https://github.com/ialbert/biostar-central) it is important to have an image upload functionality, I don't understand enough about django and databases to do it properly so rather than having to host it on the server or on an external website (like photobucket) i've come across this solution using an upload widget - http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget

The link to be added to the page:

```
<a href="#" id="upload_widget_opener">Upload multiple images</a>
```

The event listener:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
document.getElementById("upload_widget_opener").addEventListener("click", function() {

cloudinary.openUploadWidget({ cloud_name: 'demo', upload_preset: 'a5vxnzbp'}, 
  function(error, result) { console.log(error, result) });

}, false);
</script>
```

I've put the link in the correct place in the image link dialog box, and i've put the listener in the static HTML which is the pagedown_widget.html

The problem is that the script isn't executing, which Django file should i put the event listener in and how can i make it execute? I appreciate any help as i am a Django novice,

Thanks in advance.

The site is almost identical to stack exchange, the link tag appears when you click the image upload button [image]

Comment: If you look at the rendered html, does the link tag come before or after the script tag?

Comment: @Jieter The link tag appears when you click the image upload button

Comment: I mean if you look at the *source*, what is the order of the two tags? I you try to attach an event listener before the element you are trying to attach it to is available in the DOM, it's not going to work.

Comment: I think the event listener is probably attatched before the image link is added, i'll try to put it after

Comment: image: "Image <img> Ctrl+G",

        imagedescription: "enter image description here",

        imagedialog: "<a href='#' id='upload_widget_opener'>Upload multiple images</a><script src='//widget.cloudinary.com/global/all.js' type='text/javascript'></script><script type='text/javascript'>  document.getElementById('upload_widget_opener').addEventListener('click', function() {cloudinary.openUploadWidget({ cloud_name: 'demo', upload_preset: 'a5vxnzbp'}, function(error, result) { console.log(error, result) });}, false);</script>",

Comment: Putting it after directly in the Imagedialog: string doesn't work

Comment: Consider wrapping the javascript in <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function(){ .. your code .. }); </script>. Edit: Sorry just realized this is javascript not jquery .. so try to wrap it in this instead: <script type="text/javascript"> window.addEventListener('load',function(){ ..you code here .. });</script>

Comment: Hi Bobby, thanks for the suggestion. Is there an easy way to see whether it is firing? It doesn't seem to be working as i don't get any error or result in the javascript console

Comment: imagedialog: "<a href='#' id='upload_widget_opener'>Upload multiple images</a><script type='text/javascript'> window.addEventListener('load',function(){ document.getElementById('upload_widget_opener').addEventListener('click', function() {cloudinary.openUploadWidget({ cloud_name: 'demo', upload_preset: 'a5vxnzbp'}, function(error, result) { console.log(error, result) });}, false);});</script>",

Comment: p.s. I added the includes to the HTML file and I can see in the debugger that the widget JS is being imported

Comment: @BobbyC sorry i forgot to tag you in the last comment